# Google Calendar Events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, gdata, google-api-php-client

I am having some trouble adding events to Google Calendar. I can list events but when I try to add an event I am getting a 403 Forbidden Error. I am able to add events to primary, but when I try another one, in this case the one I've mnetion, I run into the 403 Forbidden Error. Here is the code I have:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Calendar');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', 'credentials/calendar.json');
define('SECRET_PATH', 'secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)));

function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    $credentials_path = CREDENTIALS_PATH;

    if (file_exists($credentials_path)) {
        $access_token = file_get_contents($credentials_path);
    } else {
        // $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        // printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $auth_url);

        // print 'Enter verification code: ';

        // $auth_code = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // $access_token = $client->authenticate($auth_code);

        // if (!file_exists(dirname($credentials_path))) {
            // mkdir(dirname($credentials_path), 0700, true);
        // }

        // file_put_contents($credentials_path, $access_token);
        // printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentials_path);
}

   $client->setAccessToken($access_token);

   if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
       $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
       file_put_contents($credentials_path, $client->getAccessToken());
   }

   return $client; 

 }



   $client = getClient();

   $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


   $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
   $event->setSummary('Appointment');
   $event->setLocation('Somewhere');
   $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
   $start->setDateTime('2015-04-14T10:00:00.000-07:00');
   $event->setStart($start);
   $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
   $end->setDateTime('2015-04-15T10:25:00.000-07:00');
   $event->setEnd($end);
   $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
   $attendee1->setEmail('leah@leahdawn.com');

   $attendees = array($attendee1);
   $event->attendees = $attendees;
   $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('leah@leahdawn.com', $event);

   echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

Specifically, the error is 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/leah%40leahdawn.com/events: (403) Forbidden.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) is a calendar id,  while `'leah@leahdawn.com'` could be a valid calendar id.   You may even be able to see this calendar if the owner has shared it with you.  This doesn't mean that the owner of said calendar has given you permission to add events to there calendar.

I suggest you run a [CalendarList: get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get)

```
 $calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->get('calendarId');
 echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

This will give you back the information about this calendar if you have access.

```
  {

 "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
 "etag": "\"1412244000929000\"",
 "id": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "colorId": "15",
 "backgroundColor": "#9fc6e7",
 "foregroundColor": "#000000",
 "selected": true,
 "accessRole": "reader",
 "defaultReminders": [
 ]
}
```

The thing to look for here is  `"accessRole": "reader",` if you don't have access to do more then read the calendar you wont be allowed to add events.

**Update:  CalendarList : List**

try going to the [Calendar list page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) at the bottom run try me.  It will also show you what calendars you have access to.

Comment: Now it is throwing an exception 'Error calling GET https://www,googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/ leah%40leahdawn.com: (404) Not found. It displays the events in the listEvents method just fine, any idea why this won't work?

Comment: check CalendarList: list  make sure that you have access to that calendar.  At the verify least that calendar will return to you the correct calendar Id you may have miss spelt it or something.    If Calendarlist.get is returning Not found I really suspect you don't have access to that calendar.